# Wine run linux command as .exe

Tags: wine

I'm trying to get a windows program to run that uses a `fastboot.exe` (by repeatedly running it with varying command-line arguments). There's a linux version of `fastboot` with the same command line format/arguments which works. Is there some way to make a `fastboot.exe` file that passes it's arguments to the linux `fastboot`?

Comment: Duplicate, on [SO]: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6004070/712526

Comment: Just as an FYI to a fellow Haskeller, you can compile HS programs for Wine by downloading the HS Platform for Windows. The compiler produces MinGW executables, and runs fine under Wine. That may or may not help with your current issue.